# NSKeyedArchiver crashing app with exception error

Tags: ios, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am trying to save an image to my Documents folder using NSCoding and NSKeyedArchiver. The app works like this: A user takes a picture, sees a preview, saves the image then can see the image in a gallery section. I do not save multiple images at the same time.

I am getting a crash and don't know if I am archiving the images incorrectly, if my photo class is set up improperly, or if my code for unarchiving is wrong. Ultimately I need to grab the objects and use them to populate a collection view.

When I call code to load the objects I get a crash that looks like this

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ImageForArchiving countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174232da0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x18533c22c 0x196fb00e4 0x1853432f4 0x1853400a8 0x18524296c 0x10001aefc 0x189ded1ec 0x189dd62c8 0x189decb88 0x189dec814 0x189de5d50 0x189db8f74 0x18a05a124 0x189db7488 0x1852f3f8c 0x1852f3230 0x1852f12e0 0x18521cf74 0x18ec7f6fc 0x189e1ed94 0x10001840c 0x19765aa08)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

My subclass code looks like this. ImageForArchiving conforms to NSCoder protocol.

**ImageForArchiving.h**

```
    @interface ImageForArchiving : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (strong) NSDate *date;
@property (strong) NSData *imageData;

+ (ImageForArchiving *)createImageWithImage:(NSData*)data andDate:(NSDate*)date;
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
```

@end

**ImageForArchiving.m**

```
@implementation ImageForArchiving

+ (ImageForArchiving *)createImageWithImage:(NSData*)data andDate:(NSDate*)date {

    ImageForArchiving *archiveImage = [[ImageForArchiving alloc] init];

    [archiveImage setDate:date];
    [archiveImage setImageData:data];

    return archiveImage;
}

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self setDate: [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"date"]];
        [self setImageData: [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"image"]];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{

    [coder encodeObject:self.date forKey:@"date"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.imageData forKey:@"image"];

}

@end
```

The code for archiving is in the preview VC where the user would view the photo after taking it. It appears as a modal popped from a segue with a block.

**PreviewViewController.m**
(save Image IBAction)

```
NSString *filePath = [self createPathForDataFile];
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.previewImage.image);
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    ImageForArchiving *imageRecord = [ImageForArchiving createImageWithImage:pngData andDate:date];
    [self saveItemsAtFilePath:filePath andImageToArchive:imageRecord];
```

creating the file path

```
- (NSString *)createPathForDataFile
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    documentsPath = [documentsPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: documentsPath] == NO)
    {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    }

    return [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];
}
```

Saving the image

```
- (void)saveItemsAtFilePath:(NSString*)filePath andImageToArchive:(ImageForArchiving*)imageRecord {

        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:imageRecord toFile:filePath];
    }
```

loading the image - this is where the crash happens

```
- (void)loadItems {
    NSString *filePath = [self createPathForDataFile];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        self.galleryItemsArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
    } else {
        self.galleryItemsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}
```

Comment: Something doesn't match. When saving, you archive a single `ImageForArchive` object. But when loading, if the file exists you unarchive the single `ImageForArchive` object but if the file doesn't exist, you create a mutable array. The error indicates it's treating an `ImageForArchive` object like an array. Fix the code to be consistent and delete any existing archive and try again.

Comment: Ok, if I call `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];` should I get a single instance or all the saved instances if multiple instances are saved? When I set the above method to `ImageForArchive` instance, I get this crash - [ImageForArchiving image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17403dec0'

Comment: The archive file will contain whatever you save last. It doesn't append. If you archive an array of objects then you get back an array of objects. If you archive a single object you get back a single object.

Comment: Ok, I think that's the part I didn't get. Thanks. If you want to copy past your comment as an answer, I will accept.